# Redirect does not working properly using spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, redirect, authentication, controller

Redirection does not work properly. I could not understand the problem because I very new to spring.

Here is my controller when I submit my form then ("schoolform") submitForm controller called and it redirect to another controller to ('form') form controller but it goes to ("login") login controller. I don't know why ?
I want to redirect schoolform to form controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/schoolform", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String submitForm(@ModelAttribute("school")School school,Model model,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse resp) {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        schoolService.update(school);
            System.out.println("Form submitted finaly, No further changes can be made.");
        return "redirect:/form.html";
    }


@RequestMapping(value = "/form", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String form(Model model,HttpServletRequest request) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String name = auth.getName(); // get logged in username
        System.out.println(name+"--------form page-----");

     }

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView login(
            @RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,
            @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout) {
        logger.info("------------------LoginController ---------------");
        System.out.println("LoginController ");
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        if (error != null) {
            model.addObject("error", "Invalid username and password!");
        }

        if (logout != null) {
            model.addObject("msg", "You've been logged out successfully.");

        }
        model.setViewName("login");
        return model;

    }
```

Comment: Try to return `redirect:/form`, without `.html` extension

Comment: Its not working

Comment: not clear from the question what is happening. which url you are hitting on form submit and it is redirecting to which url? and what behavior you exactly want to achieve.

Comment: got it. first please check by putting return "redirect:form" in the submitform method and you are not returning any thing from the form method. return a view name from the form method as well. also check if login url is mentioned as a error handling url in web.xml.

Comment: this is not working and login url is not mentioned as error handling.

Comment: Are you using spring security configuration ? is /form  a protected resource and asking you to login again ?.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not working because the method in which you are trying to redirect to a url, accepts `POST` requests. You cannot redirect from `POST` methods **UNLESS** you have a handler method that accepts `GET` method and whose `@RequestMapping` accepts the value where you are trying to redirect.

So basically, the method `submitForm` which accepts POST requests only, is trying to redirect to `/form.html`. Now, there is no method in your controller that accepts /form.html, So now you gotto have a method in your controller class whose mapping value is `/form.html` and it accepts `GET` requests:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/form.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String methodName(arg1 ..){ ... }
```